# How can I overlay an image texture with transparent alpha on a material I have created?

Tags: materials, shaders, transparency

I just need to simply add freckles onto my characters face.

I have a skin material which makes up my character completely. Then I add a new material for an area on her face which I want to have freckles. It is a png image with a transparent background.

I can kind of figure out how to make the actual alpha transparent with alpha blend and backface culling but I cannot understand how to reveal the underlying material as well.

I have looked up guides or tutorials on the shader nodes and cannot find anything. I tried it myself and it was a fail.
Can someone please help me understand how I can do this?

Comment: are you using EEVEE or Cycles?

Comment: So with all of my attempts, I have switched between both. I work in Evee but I do swap to cycles to see the results. Nothing different so far. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a UV sphere that I am going to use as an example.  The currently selected area represents where you might want the freckles.  I'm going to use a candle flame but the principle is the same.

[image]

Imagine that this is your "skin" material:

[image: "skin" material.]

In the Material properties window, add another material slot and also assign it to the skin material:

[image: 2nd material slot]

Select "Add as new material" to create a copy of the skin material:

[image: duplicate material]

rename it if you would like.  Then select assign to assign it to the faces where you want the freckles.
[image: assign the new material]

I need an additional couple steps you may not.  I marked the boundaries of the new area with seams in the UV editor, and selected the area to create a new UV Map using 'unwrap' from the UV menu:

[image: UV Unwrap]

[image: UV Map]

Modify the "skin with freckles" shader to add my alpha mixing nodes

[image: modified skin with freckles material]

and here's the result

[image: flame on skin]

You'll want to do the UV editing differently than I did, of course, to match your model.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering so quick. Here are a couple videos so you can see my issue. I did try both of your solutions and perhaps they worked but since I am so confused about what settings to change when it comes to creating an alpha channel, that is the only issue. The first video with purple skin is my origonal and the second video has both of your nodes with the results. If you notice, on the second attempt, some subsurface scattering came through interestingly enough.    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yW3UBPQEzAw   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzApbhT6PTo

Comment: You need to modify the material that makes the purple skin and add the image texture and mix node to that material.

Comment: I went ahead and adjusted my (skin) mat which was the purple that was then changed to a skin color. I assigned that base material to the entire person so I could follow these steps with your last comment. Unfortunately I didn't get any different results in terms of the alpha issue. But only a small area on her face should have freckles. The material I have been using called freckles is basically a skin material that has the image texture to combine.  It is okay if it is off a bit color wise to the main skin mat since I can adjust. Thank you for your help! Any other ideas I can try? :o

Comment: Let me edit my answer to give you a better step by step example.

Comment: I am still having the issue and I super duper apprecieate your detailed answer with step by step and photos. I am currently collecting all the info I can to build a better video as far as my attempts and to show my setup is the same. At this point I am lead to believe it is a minor alpha setting issue but I need to research just a bit more. I have tried evee and cycles but I am wondering if I do not have an alpha channel setup yet

Comment: OMG you won't believe what my issue was this whole time! I was at one point thinking that the png I had was fake, or at least was saved as a png but did not retain it's alpha channel, so I downloaded at least 2 or 3 other pngs which specifically said they had transparent backgrounds which had the same issue, regardless I opened the png up in photoshop and it did not open with an alpha channel and transparent background so I had to create my very own. I thank you for all your help! It now works :D